Ubuntu - VS code android SDK path
I have Android Studio and Vscode on the same machine. The android sdk path in AndroidStudio and the ANDROID_ROOT are set to
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk

Flutter doctor also find it correctly. For some reason Vscode tries to use the ~/Android/Sdk location when I start an emulator
[ERR] WARNING | /home/xxxxx/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-24/google_apis_playstore/x86/ is not a valid directory.
[ERR] WARNING | emulator has searched the above paths but found no valid sdk root directory.
[ERR] PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

I just cant find out where this path comes from. It may have been the path where Android Studio installed the SDK there, but then I changed it to point to the single location /usr/lib/androi-sdk.
Funny thing is that the emulator created from vscode works, but the one from android studio is seen but doesnt start due to the path issue. I cannot spot any differences between the avds under ~/.android/avd. Both avds have relative paths to system images.
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-26/default/x86/
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-24/google_apis_playstore/x86/

Tried adding "dart.androidSdkPath": "/usr/lib/android-sdk" to vscode settings but neither does it work nor do I think its relevant.
Any ideas anyone?

I still dont know the real reason behind it, but after going through flutter code where the sdk locations are determined (and everything seeminly correct) I decided to just force the location in flutter
flutter config --android-sdk /usr/lib/android-sdk

Restarting vscode after that has fixed the problem.
